# Which character is used to fill contents of password text input?

Tags: character-encoding, special-characters, typography

I need this filled-circle character for my sketch of the UI.

I have not found it in characters table on my mac.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure which is the exact one on the mac, but [bullet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullet_(typography)) is probably what you want to search for.

or use • unicode 2022.

or alternatively ⚫ 26AB (medium black circle) or ● 25CF (black circle)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Bullet is exactly, what i was seeking for :)