# Text Shadows on counter or bullet in list

Tags: css, html-lists, shadow

I want to know how to add **text-shadow to an ordered list** `</ol>`.
I've tried, the following example but it doesn't work.

```css
body {
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
  color: gray;
  background: white;
}

ol {
  text-shadow: black 0.1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
```

```html
Ordered Lists
<ol>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
  <li>content</li>
</ol>
```

My issue it tahe the **list counter doesn't have the text shadow**. I need to add text shadow to the number in the ordered list, like the 1. , or 2. , etc.

By the way, I want it to still retain like a list style where the content is indented before the number.

Comment: [Fiddle for the OP stuff](http://jsfiddle.net/cE4cc/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you also want to set the **text-shadow on the counter/bullet**, you need to put the counter/bullet in the `:before` pseudo element so that the counter/bullet can have a text-shadow like the rest of the text.

To keep the position of the counter you can set `position:absolute;` to the pseudo element and position it outside the `li` on the left with `right:100%;`.

```css
body {
    text-shadow: .1em 0.1em 0.2em;
}
ol {
    counter-reset: li;
    list-style-type: none;
}
ol li{
    position:relative;
}
ol li:before{
    content: counter(li)'.';
    counter-increment: li;
    position:absolute;
    right:100%;
    margin-right:0.5em;
}
```

```html
Ordered Lists
<ol>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: but content shadow is now gone.

Comment: @vaibhav oh sorry, I though you wanted the shadow only on the counter, here you are : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/Gn8dd/

Comment: To start with a custom value for an ordered list when you use this, for example you want to start with 2. you should do this: <ol style="counter-reset: li 1"> <li> content </li> </ol>

Comment: @edwardtorvalds browser support is very wide : https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-counters

Answer (score 0):

For custom styles on the list decoration themselves you probably need to either fake them or use custom images (or both).

This looks semi-helpful but doesn't have different values per item.

[Custom bullet symbol for <li> elements in <ul> that is a regular character, and not an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and)

If you know how many items you are going to have as a maximum you could create a custom rule for each n-th child of the ul.