# Customizing the "bullet" icons in html lists

Tags: html

What is the html syntax to create a list that uses a given character, i.e. ▲ or #, as bullet points instead of the standard circles or numbers?

Comment: refer [Custom bullet symbol for <li> elements in <ul> that is a regular character, and not an image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12216973/1675954

Comment: You can customise bullets using css . follow this link for that : http://techforluddites.com/replacing-list-bullets-with-images-using-css/

Comment: You can create a image of that character and use it as a background image instead of regular character. In that way you have more control over it.

Comment: @sasith, that is not the way to do it, because it is really dirty! And there are native methods to realise the requested behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

If you like you can use CSS :before Selector to edit your list item. Then you can use css `.content:'--unicode here--'` to add the character you want. Here is example [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v9zvkpjv/) and here is link to get [unicodes.](http://www.evotech.net/blog/2007/04/named-html-entities-in-numeric-order/)

But you should set `.li{list-style:none}` in your css.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is a custom bullet icon:

```
ul {
        list-style-image: url('sqpurple.gif');
    }
```

The

```
list-style-type
```

style in CSS applied to the `ul` and `ol` tags.

This [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9d67oqsL/) has some useful list icon types. More types of icons are supported though:

```
ul.a {list-style-type: circle;}
ul.b {list-style-type: disc;}
ul.c {list-style-type: square;}

ol.d {list-style-type: armenian;}
ol.e {list-style-type: cjk-ideographic;}
ol.f {list-style-type: decimal;}
ol.g {list-style-type: decimal-leading-zero;}
ol.h {list-style-type: georgian;}
ol.i {list-style-type: hebrew;}
ol.j {list-style-type: hiragana;}
ol.k {list-style-type: hiragana-iroha;}
ol.l {list-style-type: katakana;}
ol.m {list-style-type: katakana-iroha;}
ol.n {list-style-type: lower-alpha;}
ol.o {list-style-type: lower-greek;}
ol.p {list-style-type: lower-latin;}
ol.q {list-style-type: lower-roman;}
ol.r {list-style-type: upper-alpha;}
ol.s {list-style-type: upper-latin;}
ol.t {list-style-type: upper-roman;}
```

Comment: she's looking for custom, not standard, list-style types

Comment: @RachelGallen Which is exactly why I included the image list style. That covers the requirement doesn't it?