# Custom HTML bullets don't work in IE 11 when loading from file via Excel

Tags: html, css, excel

I'm trying to create an Excel tool that allows people to use templated HTML and preview it within an IE tab. I use en Excel form to create an HTML file, which is saved locally and navigated to within an instance of IE.

Unfortunately, the code doesn't work when I load it from file (it seems to ignore the `li:before` styling), however it seems to work fine in Chrome, and fine in IE [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and).

I'm using the following CSS / HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <frame name="prevHtml">
    <head>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            body 
            {
                font-size:14px;
                font-family: Helvetica;
            }
            h2 
            {
                font-size:14px;
                margin:10px 0px;
                font-family: Helvetica;
            } 
            p 
            {
                font-family: Helvetica;
            }
            ul {
                margin-left: 0;  
                padding-left: 0;  
                list-style-type: none;
            }
            li {
                position: relative;  
                left: 1em;
            }
            li:before 
            {
                position: absolute;
                left: -1em;
                content: "-";
            }
            table.dims
            {
                font-size:14px;
                font-family: Helvetica;
                border-collapse: collapse; 
                border:solid 1px #eee; 
                border-bottom: 2px solid #eee;
                margin-bottom:30px;
            } 
            table.dims tr:hover 
            {
                background: #f4f4f4;
            }
            table.dims tr:hover td 
            {
                color: #555;
            }
            table.dims td
            {
                padding:3px 12px 3px 12px; 
                border-right:solid 1px #eee;
                font-size:13px;
                text-align:left
            }
            table.dims th 
            {
                padding:5px 0px;
                text-align:left
            } 
            .grey 
            {
                background-color:#eee;
            } 
            .links 
            {
                background-color:#000; 
                color:#fff; 
                padding:6px; 
                font-size:12px; 
                margin-right:10px;
            } 
            #bar 
            {
                float:left; 
                width:980px; 
                margin-bottom:15px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <ul>
            -<li>item1</li>
            -<li>item2</li>
            -<li>item3</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Any ideas?!?!

UPDATE:

After simplifying the below code, saving it to a text file and opening that in IE 11, it looks like this:

[css issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWJAw.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frame name="prevHtml">
    <head>
        <style media="screen" type="text/css">
            body {
              font-size: 14px;
              font-family: Helvetica;
            }
            ul {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              list-style-type: none;
            }
            .absolute li {
              position: relative;
              left: 1em;
              width: 99% /* add this [or another value that fits you best] to avoid horizontal scrollbar */
            }
            .absolute li:before {
              position: absolute;
              left: -1em;
              content: "-";
            }
            .relative li {
             /* position: relative; not needed in this case */
            }
            .relative li:before {
              position: relative;
              content: "-";
              margin-right:.6em
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> absolute ::before </h1>
            <ul class="absolute">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
        <hr />
        <h1> relative ::before </h1>
            <ul class="relative">
              <li>item1</li>
              <li>item2</li>
              <li>item3</li>
            </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pcda1dt6/) what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: that's exactly what I'm trying to achieve!

Comment: but it ends up looking like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/pcda1dt6/2/) instead

Comment: Use that code and include the li:before class like in my fiddle and you are done. I posted the complete answer below, you can accept it if it's working for you. thanks

Comment: the problem remains! check my update to the question where I've used your css/html and still got the issue (attached screenshot).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stripping your code to the basics, it works, take a look:

**Snippet** with 2 options **`absolute`** and **`relative`** on `::before`

```css
body {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}
.absolute li {
  position: relative;
  left: 1em;
  width: 99% /* add this [or another value that fits you best] to avoid horizontal scrollbar */
}
.absolute li:before {
  position: absolute;
  left: -1em;
  content: "-";
}

.relative li {
 /* position: relative; not needed in this case */

}
.relative li:before {
  position: relative;
  content: "-";
  margin-right:.6em
}
```

```html
<h1> absolute ::before </h1>
<ul class="absolute">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
<hr />
<h1> relative ::before </h1>
<ul class="relative">
  <li>item1</li>
  <li>item2</li>
  <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

*SS IE11*

---

[image: SS IE11]

#### Note: This was tested on IE11 and works 100%

Comment: I thought as much, however if I save the following to a text file and then open it in IE 11, it ignores the '-'

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<frame name="prevHtml">
 <head>
  <style media="screen" type="text/css">
  body {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
  }
  ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
  }
  li {
    position: relative;
    left: 1em;
  }
  li:before {
    position: absolute;
    left: -1em;
    content: "-";
  }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <ul>
   <li>item1</li>
   <li>item2</li>
   <li>item3</li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>

Comment: the problem remains - check the update to the question, using your html saved as a .html and opened in IE 11

Comment: here is your issue: `<frame name="prevHtml">` just remove it!

Comment: deleted that line and same problem in IE 11. if i open the file in chrome or firefox, i get the correct bullets....

Comment: did you try saving the code as a .html and navigating to the path in IE?

Comment: I updated my answer with the test (that I already had done). here is the image , just in case [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZESyB.jpg). I tested locally and on the server, both works

Comment: very weird. looks like it's something to do with my install of IE 11. many thanks for your help. marked as solved as it works on a colleague's PC too.

Comment: a piece of advice, run anti-malware/spyware , it might something related to that

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using **li:before** class with content:'-' rule in your CSS.

```
li:before{
  position:aboslute;
  margin-right:1em;
  content:'-';
}
```

And just use a simple unordered list in your HTML code

```
<ul>
    <li>item1</li>
    <li>item2</li>
    <li>item3</li>
</ul>
```

This is a fiddle with the working code: http://jsfiddle.net/pcda1dt6/3/

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't seem to work when I load into IE 11 from an html file. See the update to the original question above.