# How to align discs (bullets) of UL with the left edge of an enclosing DIV?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

#### A regular list

This is a regular list that serves as the basis of my question.

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque, quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
<li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc, eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
<li>Nulla id</li>
<li>Nam ut</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

The font-size is blown up to `2em` so that we can clearly see additional unwanted space around the bullet points in proposed solutions.

#### Setting left-padding to 0 does not solve it completely

I want to align the discs (the bullets) of the list with the left edge of the `div` element. So I try something like this.

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  list-style-position: inside;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque, quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
<li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc, eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
<li>Nulla id</li>
<li>Nam ut</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

This solution would have been nice if the indentation of the wrapped lines were not lost. I still want the wrapped lines to be aligned with the beginning of the first character of the first line like they are in a regular list.

#### Setting left-padding to 1em does not solve it completely

This is one of the solutions proposed in the answers but this does not work as well. We can see additional horizontal space between the left edge of the DIV and the bullet-point discs.

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque, quis dictum metus
      porttitor.</li>
    <li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc, eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
    <li>Nulla id</li>
    <li>Nam ut</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

#### Question

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Downvoters, could you please offer some feedback about how this question may be improved?

Comment: Lone Learner, would you like to write a feedback to my answer below, please.

Comment: @LoneLearner, build your own bullet points using <span> tag..It is the best solution and anytime you can customize it's gaps as well as it's appearance such as squares, triangle etc. Try my solution below.

Answer (score 5):

You can create your own bullet and you will be able to easily control size and distance:

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  margin-left:20px;
  font-size: 2em;
}
ul {
 list-style:none;
 padding:0;
}
li {
  display:flex;
}
li:before {
  content:"";
  width:0.4em;
  height:0.4em;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:#000;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  margin-top:0.4em;
  flex-shrink:0;
}
body {
 background:pink;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique</li>
    <li>Nulla id</li>
    <li>Nam ut</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div style="font-size: 1em;">
  <ul>
    <li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique</li>
    <li>Nulla id</li>
    <li>Nam ut</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add to your second example `margin-left: 0.84em;` and `list-style-position: outside;` and you will have what you need:

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}

ul {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0.84em;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque, quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
<li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc, eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
<li>Nulla id</li>
<li>Nam ut</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}
div ul {
  list-style:none;
}
div ul li {
  
}
div ul li .disc {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 0.5em;
  height: 0.5em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: #000;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<ul>
<li><span class="disc"></span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque, quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
<li><span class="disc"></span>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc, eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
<li><span class="disc"></span>Nulla id</li>
<li><span class="disc"></span>Nam ut</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sampath_Madhuranga/4wv7kuep/5/

Use your own styles to show bullet points..That is the best solution for this issue...

Try this snippet..This may works  for you.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways.
Check the https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/list-style/ which shows you can order the list 'list-style-position' property.

Otherwise we can use the symbols or any icons or images look at this link "[Custom bullet symbol for <li> elements in <ul> that is a regular character, and not an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and)" which gives complete descruption of listview alignment.

In general it will add before property to the li, we can write our own.Please let me know if anything required

Answer (score 0):

You can also try using `background-images`, with minimal css, it works exactly the same way as `pseudo :before and :after` as said by others earlier. This would also give you tight control over the size of the bullet. please have a look at the below snippet :)

```css
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 15em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 2em;
}
ul {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
ul li {
  padding-left: 1em;
  background: url("https://via.placeholder.com/10.png/000/000") no-repeat left .5em / .25em;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit
      amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque,
      quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
    <li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc,
      eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
    <li>Nulla id</li>
    <li>Nam ut</li>
  </ul>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div style="font-size: 1em">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse in pretium mauris. Aliquam ultrices ipsum sit
      amet auctor porta. Donec et metus quis dolor dignissim euismod non a sem. Sed accumsan risus quis ipsum pellentesque,
      quis dictum metus porttitor.</li>
    <li>Etiam et interdum ipsum, quis venenatis augue. Sed euismod, sem eget tristique molestie, arcu massa scelerisque nunc,
      eget scelerisque elit sem vitae nulla.</li>
    <li>Nulla id</li>
    <li>Nam ut</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
div {
  background: lightgreen;
  width: 20em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

div ul{
  padding-left:0;
  list-style-position: outside;
}
div ul li{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Try this CSS instead.

Comment: This does not work. It leaves extra margin between the left edge and the discs.