# Replace bullet points with emojis (or other Unicode characters) (But Don't change nested bullets)

Tags: css, unicode, html-lists, emoji

In my sandbox here:

```css
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(1):before {content: "\26A1  ";}
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(2):before {content: " ";}
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(3):before {content: " ";}
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(4):before {content: " ";}
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(5):before {content: " ";}
.thunderbolt li:nth-child(6):before {content: "\2685";}
```

```html
<div>
<ul class="thunderbolt">
<li>ThunderBolt devices only get recognized by BootCamp on boot.</li>
<li>If you unplug your ThunderBolt device while using Windows, you'll have to shut down then reboot your OS to get it recognized again.</li>
<li>Disable <b>Fast Startup </b>in Windows 8/10.</li>
<ul>
<li>Also try holding <b>Shift </b>when you click&nbsp;<b>Start </b>&gt; <b>Shut down</b>.</li>
</ul>
<li>Wait a solid chunk of seconds on the login screen after boot to allow BootCamp to configure Thunderbolt devices.</li>
<li><b>Sleep&nbsp;</b>simply does not work in BootCamp with a ThunderBolt device connected.</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

http://www.cssdesk.com/M6Cyz

I want the unicode characters to *replace* the bullet points. Instead, the characters are just showing up *alongside* the bullet points, in-line with the text.

Also, I don't want the `.thunderbolt` class to apply to the nested `<ul>`--I just want that to be a standard bullet point.

I've tried `.thunderbolt list-style: none` but all that did was make my thunderbolt symbol disappear.

Also, the resulting webpage displayed skips the character in `.thunderbolt li:nth-child(4):before {content: " ";}` for the 4th child and displays the character from `.thunderbolt li:nth-child(5):before {content: " ";}` instead. It seems the code treats the one nested  `<li>` as if it were the 4th child in the parent `<ul>`.

---

1. How do I *replace* the bullent points in a `<ul>` with a unicode character?
2. How do I tell the CSS to skip nested `<ul>`'s when applying `nth-child(n)` properties?

Comment: @MrLister Sorry it's been a while since I've been on here. Added the code to the post contents

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul.thunderbolt > li:nth-child(1) {
  list-style: "\26A1   ";
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.thunderbolt > li:nth-child(2) {
  margin-top: 10px;  
  list-style: "  ";
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.thunderbolt > li:nth-child(3) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: "  ";
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.thunderbolt > li:nth-child(5) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: "  ";
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.thunderbolt > li:nth-child(6) {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style: "  ";
  list-style-position: outside;
}
ul.thunderbolt ul li {
  margin-top: 10px;
  list-style-type: circle;
}
```

```html
<ul class="thunderbolt">
<li>ThunderBolt devices only get recognized by BootCamp on boot.</li>
<li>If you unplug your ThunderBolt device while using Windows, you'll have to shut down then reboot your OS to get it recognized again.</li>
<li>Disable <b>Fast Startup </b>in Windows 8/10.</li>
<ul>
<li>Also try holding <b>Shift </b>when you click&nbsp;<b>Start </b>&gt; <b>Shut down</b>.</li>
</ul>
<li>Wait a solid chunk of seconds on the login screen after boot to allow BootCamp to configure Thunderbolt devices.</li>
<li><b>Sleep&nbsp;</b>simply does not work in BootCamp with a ThunderBolt device connected.</li>
</ul>
```

- The `> li` makes the style changes only affect elements in the parent list.
- I used  `ul.class_name ul li` to change the `list-style-type` of the one nested `<li>` item to an open `circle` instead of a closed `disc`.
- I was doing this in Blogspot, which has a built-in style sheet (that I didn't want to backup, edit, then reupload), so I had to add `!important` after my changes in order for them to apply.

  - Examples:
  - `list-stye: "\26A1   "!important;`
  - `list-style-position: outside!important;`
- The CSS still considered the nested `<li>` as `nth-child(4)`, so I had to skip it in my `nth-child(n)` numbering in my parent list. (Notice I do `nth-child(3)` then skip to `nth-child(5)`.)

[Credit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58914844/3511695)

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 1:** If you use unicode instead of bullets, you will need to use,

```
.thunderbolt li: {
   position: relative;
   list-style: none;
   overflow: hidden;
}
.thunderbolt li:after {
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: -2%;
   transform: transletX(-50%);
}
```

And please use your unicode as a `position: absolute;`, I hope your code is easy solution. Same css will work all `li` but individually you just change `content: 'here is your unicode';` I hope it will be easiest way to implement unicode items instead of bullet item.

**Answer 2:** If you use `.thundebolt > li` then i hope it will work only on specific list. You can try it.

**Note:** If you have better solution let me, i want to know more from you, thank you!

Comment: After getting rid of the `:` in `.thunderbolt li: {`, all that seemed to do was get rid of the bullet point. I want the unicode characters to _take the place of_ the bullet points.