# I am trying to use HTML Code as a List-Style-Type

Tags: html, listitem

I would like to use an HTML Symbol (→) as a bullet for my list items.  I have tried using an image but it just doesn't look right.  I have also looked in to using the :before selector, but HTML code does not seem to work in that instance.  Is there a way that I can use HTML code as a bullet point, and if so, how?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure why an image "doesn't look right", it's whatever you assign it to be. But if you want an alternative and don't care about IE you could load a font with ligatures in it and then just use `->`.

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple actually.

```css
ul {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 1.2em;
}
ul li:before {
    content: "→";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

This has already been answered in [Custom bullet symbol for <li> elements in <ul> that is a regular character, and not an image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and), by the way.

Thanks to [Jpsy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/430742/jpsy) for this code.