# Make <li> list item bullets with star icon using reactstrap/react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, frontend, reactstrap

I am a ML pro trying to get up to speed on frontend. How do I create some tag:{li} list item bullets with a custom star bullet picture. Can someone provide full html/css example?

Thanks much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom bullet symbol for <li> elements in <ul>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7698764/custom-bullet-symbol-for-li-elements-in-ul-that-is-a-regular-character-and)

Answer (score 1):

Try it, but before it remove all default styling

```
li:before {
  content: "★";
}
```

List with unicode symbols:
https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_utf_symbols.asp