# How to create a &raquo bullet?

Tags: html, css

I have very little experience with coding and am trying to change a bullet from the stock outlined circle to a right quote (&raquo).

This is my code for the current bullet:

```
<li style="font-family: Helvetica,Calibri,Arial,sans-serif; color: #cbcbcb;"></li>
```

and I would just like to add "`»`" into the code.

Comment: Solution is also well covered in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203252/unicode-character-as-bullet-for-list-item-in-css
Please search on SO better. Sorry but downvote for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can set

```
ul { list-style: none; }
```

And then use CSS2 `before` pseudo-element

```
ul li:before {
    content: "\00BB";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jonigiuro/hsLuK/

You can read about pseudo-elements here: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after

Answer (score 0):

You can change with custom bullet from an image. Just create the image with the bullet you want, and use this CSS property:

```
ul {
  list-style-image: url('bullet.gif');
}
```