# Unicode as bullet not indenting second line

Tags: html, css, unicode, html-lists

## What I have:

An unordered list that uses a Unicode character for the bullets.

I achieved this using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13546879/2971649) answer to this question: [Unicode character as bullet for list-item in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3203252/2971649)

## My problem:

The solution I'm using is only effective for single-line list-items. For multi-line list-items, the text of the second line (and all following lines), rather than indenting, drops beneath the bullet.

## My code:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\2713';
  margin: 0 1em;
  /* any design */
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Single-line.</li>
  <li>Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.
    Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.</li>
</ul>
```

## My question:

Is there a CSS solution (without editing mark-up) that will prevent text dropping under the Unicode bullet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `display: flex` property on `li` elements. Or you could use `display: table` on `li` element and `display: table-cell` on pseudo-element. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/s6ob0xfy/3/)

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0px;
}
li {
  display: flex;
}
ul li:before {
  content: '\2713';
  margin: 0 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Single-line.</li>
  <li>Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.
    Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've opted to set `display:flex;`. Very simple and efficient. Thanks for a pure CSS solution.  I originally thought I would have wrap the list-item text in `<span>`.

Comment: For the `display: table-cell;` I had to assign the bullet's margin values to padding as the margin values are ignored ([fork](https://jsfiddle.net/Clarus_Dignus/woqp8rvc/4/)). For the `display: flex;` method, any list-items containing a link, squashes the link to the right of the list-item. I was unable to resolve this but you can view the problem in action [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Clarus_Dignus/2ekzwyn5/5/).

Comment: Easiest solution with flex is to wrap `li` content in one `div` element like this https://jsfiddle.net/2ekzwyn5/7/

Answer (score 1):

Give `li` a left padding and then use the same value for the width of the `li:before` and the same value but negative for the left margin of `li:before`. Remember to display `li:before` as `inline-block` otherwise the `width` will not be applied:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding-left: 2em;
}

ul li:before {
  content: '\2713';
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2em;
  margin-left: -2em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Single-line.</li>
  <li>Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.
    Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line. Multi-line.</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for providing an alternative solution. I have selected Nenad Vracar's answer because it requires one line of code. I.e. `display:flex;`.

Comment: Yes, the flex is a nice trick, but you cannot use it if you want to support older browsers.

Comment: I didn't consider browser support. Thanks.